# JS - Loop through object and output value if certain value exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object with nested arrays and I'm trying to loop through the object to see if `$id: taxonomy/group_aaa` exists. If it exists, then I want to get all the `$id` values in root and also inside `term_parents`.

In the example data, first `term` have `taxonomy/group_aaa`, so I want to get the `$id` values in root and also inside `term_parents`.

In the second `term`, it does not have `taxonomy/group_aaa`, so I do not want to get any `$id` values.

The data could have multiple `term`s. I have code that loops through the object which gets all the `$id`. How do I update the code for what I want to achieve?

I need to get these values: `12345, 22345, 33345, 44345`

Here's my code:

```
function getTaxonomyValues(object) {
  return object && typeof object === 'object'
    ? [...('$id' in object ? [object.$id.replace('taxonomy/', '')] : []), ...Object.values(object).flatMap(getTaxonomyValues)]
    : [];
}

function taxonomyData(taxo) {
  const taxonomoyData = [];
  if (taxo.constructor === Array) {
    taxonomoyData.push(getTaxonomyValues(taxo.sample_terms));
  }

  return taxonomoyData;
}
```

Here's my data (fixed):

```
{
  "$parent_level": [
    {
      "sample_terms": [
        {
          "term": {
            "$id": "taxonomy/12345",
            "term_parents": [
              {
                "$id": "taxonomy/22345",
                "term_parents": [
                  {
                    "$id": "taxonomy/33345",
                    "term_parents": [
                      {
                        "$id": "taxonomy/44345"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "term_groups": [
              {
                "$id": "taxonomy/group_aaa"
              },
              {
                "$id": "taxonomy/group_bbb"
              }
            ],
            "term_relations": [
              {
                "$id": "taxonomy/21354"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "$id": "taxonomy/92345",
            "term_parents": [
              {
                "$id": "taxonomy/92345",
                "term_parents": [
                  {
                    "$id": "taxonomy/93345",
                    "term_parents": [
                      {
                        "$id": "taxonomy/94345"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "term_groups": [
              {
                "$id": "taxonomy/group_bbb"
              }
            ],
            "term_relations": [
              {
                "$id": "taxonomy/91354"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[See attached image for more details on which values I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ6h5.png)

Comment: Your data are incomplete. You have a property without a containing object, so it's unclear where your code starts from; perhaps `taxo` the first object in `$parent_level`? It seems like your are trying to do too much in one line. Maybe try to use loops and/or reduce calls, then whittle that down to fewer lines if you feel the need.

Comment: I have cleaned up the code and json a bit and put them here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-drake-81cge?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. Its relying on for loops for data parsing. We can use filters and flatmaps but then debugging and data manipulation would be difficult. Its not optimised but it'll do the trick:

```
const getIdSet = (groupId, list) => {    
   let results = [];
   
   list.forEach(data => {
       const terms = data['sample_terms'].filter(t=> t['term']['term_groups'].some(group => group.$id.replace('taxonomy/', '')==groupId));
       
       terms.forEach(term => {
         let parent = [term.term];
         let index = 0;
         results.push(parent[index].$id); 
          
         while(index<parent.length) {
           parent[index]['term_parents'].forEach(tp => {
             results.push(tp.$id);
             if(tp['term_parents']) { parent.push(tp); }
           });
           index++;
         }
       });
   });
 
  return results.map(id => id.replace('taxonomy/', ''));
};
   
console.log(getIdSet('group_aaa', $parent_level));
// ["12345","22345","33345","44345"]
```

The code exclusively rely on the data structure. First we filter out the list data for the required group id. For this I iterate the elements of `$parent_level` and for each `sample_terms` we checked if the key `term.term_groups` has any item that gives true result for our condition. For this I used `Array.some` with the condition that group id is equals the required group id after removing the prefix *'taxomony/'*. For the next part I used iterative DFS (Depth First Seach using terms.forEach). Where I used `parent` array as a stack and I checked if there exists a `term` key such that it has `term_parents` child key. If it has then push it into `parent` stack for next iteration. The same procedure continues until we are at the end of our stack. For every `term_parents` if it has another `term_parents` key the we keep pushing it in the stack and our `while` loop continue to execute and in the meantime we keep pushing the `$id` in our `results` array. Finally we have all the required`term_parents.$id` in the `results` array and in the end we just removed the prefix *'taxomony/'* from all its elements using `Array.map`. You can see the sample code in here:  https://ideone.com/togxhM